# Altering table level caching policy in a follower ADX database

Tags: azure-data-explorer

If we have a leader and a follower cluster , I know we can explicitly set a different caching policy for a follower database than the one on the leader. But what if I want to explicitly specify caching policy for a specific table in the follower database and not across the entire follower database? I have not found any command for doing something like that in the online documentation.

Basically the following command will do it across the entire follower database:-

```
.alter follower database MyDB caching-policies-modification-kind = union
```

I am looking for something like this (obviously this command is not valid):-

```
.alter follower table MyDB.MyTable caching-policies-modification-kind = union
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is this:

```
.alter follower database MyDb tables (Table1, Table2) policy caching hot = 7d
```

or

```
.alter follower database MyDb table Table1 policy caching hot = 7d
```

See more in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/cluster-follower#table-level-commands)